# Hazelcast - Queue with no listeners, or broadcasting to one of many subscribers

Tags: java, hazelcast

I have an architecture where there are a set of "daemon" processes that form my platform. These daemon processes are full Hazelcast members and are the datastore for all data in the application. The actual business logic is segregated from the daemons and resides in a large number of microservice style components that are located either physically on the same server or on different machines (vms, containers, etc).  The services can modify data in the datastore and subscribe to events in the datastore from the daemons, but the model is actually quite different and abstracted from Hazelcast's map view so my events are not as simple as listening to map modifications but are generated when multiple maps are modified in certain ways. The service clients (Hazelcast lite members) define the events that they want to listen to.  The catch is, multiple instances (any number) of each flavour of service component could be running and I only want one instance (any one) to handle the each event (i.e. round-robin or load balancing).

My current solution is to use a Hazelcast queue. The Daemon's listen to events on maps and decide when to trigger an event based on those maps. The daemon that is the owner of the key is the one that will trigger the event so that the event is only triggered in one place. I push this event onto a queue, which each instance of a listener for this event is connected to. Thus, whoever gets to the event first processes it.

For example, I have a datasource microservice called IncomingBondPrices that puts the prices into the daemon datastore.  I have 10 instances of a separate microservice called priceProcessor. When a price reaches a certain threshold the daemons trigger an event (let's call it "PriceThresholdReached").  I want one and only one of the 10 instances of priceProcessor to handle each event so if I am streaming in hundreds or thousands of prices the load of handling the events is split across my instances of priceProcessor.

My concern is what happens if there are no consumers? I can't find any way to count the number of consumers on a hazelcast queue. The system is entirely dynamic, the services start-up and send the definitions of events that their interested in to the daemons. It is possible for 1, 2, 20, or 100 instances of any given service to be started and it is possible that they may all be shut down and there will no longer be any subscribers for the event. If there are currently no subscribers to a given event i'd like to destroy the queue and not push any events to it. I do not want events to queue up if there are no subscribers...

How could I go about managing this? The only way I can come up with is to keep a count of the subscribers for each event type in the daemons and destroy the queues when that drops to 0. But my concern is that services will most likely be killed without a graceful shutdown so they won't have a chance to explicitly tell the daemon they're not listening anymore.  Managing this would require me to explicitly check that all members are still alive or subscribe to the events when Hazlecast has found that a member has disconnected and then track down all if that member's subscriptions to end them. Is there a better way to do this? It seems overly complex. Ideally what I would like is for some way to find on the queue how many current members are running a take() on the queue at any given time and if that is 0 and there is no data on the queue then destroy it.

Thank-you,
Troy.

Answer (score 0):

What I can suggest to you, is create a dedicated ISet (or IMap) with the name "registerConsumers" for instance. Each of consumers writes its id into the set and removes it on shutdown hook.
Producers checks initially the set and registers an ItemListener to be updated. The question what to do, if process of the listener failed without good luck? Hope to load balancing - will start a new instance and you will see new one.  If you used IMap, then consumer cans update its time (in the value of the map) periodically, while producer checks periodically last update and removes guys which did not update time. This way, if yo see that there are no consumers, then simply persist data in another storage, waiting up to a consumer available. Why to destroy queues- finally a consuming microservice must start at a time.